# How to define the webpage displayed when a user receives a 401 http error code?

Tags: http, http-status-code-401

Is it possible to define what web page is showed when a user receives a 401 HTTP error response?

Or is it always a default page displayed by the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated than it sounds.

You can define the error page on the server and make it say anything you want, but that doesn't actually mean that the user will see it.

For example, here's how to do it in [IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/), and here's [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

The catch is that some browsers like Internet Explorer will eat the actual 404 page and display a "Friendly" error message. This is configurable in the browser, but I don't beleive you can do anything from the server side.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot!